# Solving inequalities number line

Tags: inequality, education, number-line

So I am currently doing inequality problems and i have the answer to the question but am unsure on how to put that onto a number line.

The question is $-7+b≤6b-2<7b+1$.

The answers i got for this are $b≥-1$ and $b>-3$ and am wondering on if the answer is correct and how to put this onto a number line help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got the same as you, so $b\geq -1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\color{red}{-7+b} ≤ \color{green}{6b-2} < \color{blue}{7b+1}$ means two inequalities:

**$(1)$** $\color{red}{-7+b} ≤ \color{green}{6b-2}$.

Solving **$(1)$** gives $-1 \leq b$.

**$(2)$** $ \color{green}{6b-2} < \color{blue}{7b+1}$.

Solving **$(2)$** gives $-3 < b$.

In total we have $b \geq -1 >-3$.

$b \geq -1$ is enough.

Comment: $-7+b≤6b-2<7b+1$ are *two* inequalities. $(3)$ is implied by $(1)$ and $(2)$, and solving it is redundant.

Comment: $x\leq y<z$ means that $x\leq y$, $y<z$ **and** $x<z$.

Comment: $x \le y$ and $y < z$ **implies** $x < z$ (transitivity of $<$).

Comment: You're right!!!
I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go step wise!

First solve $-7+b\le 6b-2\implies -7+2\le 6b-b\implies b\ge-1$

Now next $6b-2< 7b+1\implies -2-1< 7b-6b\implies b> -3$

So yes, you are right. Now to proceed note that $-1>-3$. Thus $b\ge -1$ staisfies both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I like the following way:
$$-7+b\leq 6b-2<7b+1$$ it's
$$-5\leq 5b<6b+3$$ or
$$-1\leq b$$ and $$b>-3$$ or
$$b\geq-1.$$

Comment: It should not be a OR statement because for the inequalities  to hold you will have to take intersection of the conclusions